# jquery and css solution to toggle show/hide with text in the html

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

So I created the following jquery that shows/hides a div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#me").hide();
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#me").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#me").show();
  });
});
```

This is some text

Hide

Show

http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/7/
It works fine. But I need to make it work so that instead of having a separate show and hide text, I need to toggle show and hide.
But main problem is I dont want to have the text in the javascript file for internationalization purposes.
It's ok if the text resides in the html. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: There is a toggle function in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="me" style="display:none;"> This is some text</div>
<div id="clickContainer">
    <div id="hide" style="display:none;">Hide</div>
    <div id="show">Show</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickContainer").click(function(){
        $("#me").toggle();
        $("#hide").toggle();
        $("#show").toggle();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Html :

```
<div id="me"> This is some text</div>
<div id="toggle">toggle</div>
```

Js:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
  $("#me").toggle();
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/8/

Updated fiddle  `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/13/

Comment: Possibly splitting hairs, but I would rename the div ID toggle, lest that command word be confusing to the newbie (wondering if use of the term is somehow important)

Comment: @pXL. can I change the toggle text to something else upon hiding it? in my html file?

Comment: @pXL.I meant my html file instead of javascript file. This is for internationalization purposes.

Comment: @pXL. Can you post the above jsfiddle in your answer, so that I can accept yours instead of the other.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#me").hide();
  $("#hide").click(function(){
      $("#me").toggle();
      $(this).text(function(i, val) {
          return val === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
      });
  });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/9/)**

Comment: i had posted this in my question. I need to figure out a way to add 'Show' 'Hide' text in my html instead of javascript. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/10/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#me").toggle();
        $(this).text(function(){return $('#me:visible').length?'Hide':'Show'});
    }).triggerHandler('click');
});
```